# Could not find implicit value inside singleton object

Tags: scala, implicit

I have this code:

```
trait Context {
  implicit val e: Encoder

  trait Encoder {
    def write(): Unit = {
      println("Test")
    }
  }

}

trait AsyncEncoders {
  this: Context =>

  class AsyncEncoder extends Encoder {
  }

  implicit val e = new AsyncEncoder()
}

class ConcreteContext extends Context with AsyncEncoders {
}
```

When I use it like this (**case 1**):

```
object Main extends App {
  implicit val c = new ConcreteContext()

  import c._

  implicitly[Encoder].write()
}
```

then it compiles and prints `Test`.

But when I try to call the same code inside singleton object (**case 2**):

```
object TestObject {
  def apply()(implicit c: ConcreteContext): Unit = {
    import c._
    implicitly[Encoder].write()
  }
}

object Main extends App {
  implicit val c = new ConcreteContext()

  TestObject()
}
```

compilation fails with:

> path/to/Main.scala:29: could not find implicit value for parameter e: c.Encoder 
>        implicitly[c.Encoder].write()

If I change (**case 3**):

```
implicit val e = new AsyncEncoder()
```

to

```
implicit val e: Encoder = new AsyncEncoder()
```

then it compiles and runs as expected.

But for some reason this is not acceptable for me.

Why does compilation fail in the above case?

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but just to be clear, you're fighting against Scala here. Things would be much smoother, and the type inference paths more well-documented, if you implemented `Encoder` as a typeclass instead of a path-dependent type.

Comment: Seems to be having trouble with path-dependent types that come in the form of implicit parameters.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what is wrong here, but this does compile in Scala 2.12.0.

Comment: @Jasper-M Yes, it does compile in Scala 2.12.0. Thanks! So it's Scala 2.11.* compiler issue.

Comment: Hmm, your `Encoder` trait is SAM and they've changed treatment of SAMs in 2.12. Not sure if this is the root cause why it compiles in 2.12 and errors in 2.11, but this is my first intuition.

Comment: @PiotrKrzemiński I tried to add one more method to `Encoder` but it still does not compile in 2.11 but compiles in 2.12.

Comment: They also changed some things to the generation of fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it said in comments there is no issue in Scala 2.12.0.

For Scala 2.11.8 I used the following workaround assuming that `Encoder` will have only one method:

```
trait Context {
  implicit val e: Encoder

  type BaseEncoder = () => Unit

  type Encoder <: BaseEncoder
}

trait AsyncEncoders {
  this: Context =>

  type Encoder = AsyncEncoder

  class AsyncEncoder extends BaseEncoder {
    override def apply(): Unit = {
      println("Test")
    }
  }

  implicit val e = new AsyncEncoder()
}

class ConcreteContext extends Context with AsyncEncoders {
}

object TestObject {
  def apply()(implicit c: ConcreteContext): Unit = {
    import c._
    implicitly[Encoder].apply()
  }
}

object Main extends App {
  implicit val c = new ConcreteContext()

  TestObject()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that the problem is not the fact that you use object, but that you are accepting `ConcreteContext`, as an argument: `ConcreteContext.e`'s type is `AsyncEncoder`, not `Encoder`.

Many times I observed, that, when it comes to Scala, it is better to treat arguments as invariants unless specified otherwise (e.g. macwire often fails if you don't cast impl type to interface type - it is not completely predicatable though, most of the time it works).

As you observed setting e type explicitly to `Encoder` would solve the issue. So would changing `ConcreteContext` to `Context`. My guess is that it is either a matter of invariance or limitation of a compiler's type inference engine.

Comment: I would argue that one shouldn't play with path-dependent types very much, instead. It would be very difficult to write code as if all method parameters were invariant. An `AsyncEncoder` is also an `Encoder`. You would lose most of `Encoder`'s usefulness if you always needed to specify a specific sub-type you wanted.

Comment: Are we talking about best practices here, or the reason behind observed behavior?

Comment: Both, really. If path-dependent types aren't in play, the implicits resolve consistently.

Comment: Path-dependant types is just one use case - I had more issues with implicits in the past when it was just a matter of `implicitly[MyClass]` vs `implicit val mc = new MyClassImpl`. That's why I am suspecting that's it is more of a engine's limitation.

Comment: Actually I want to understand the reason behind observed behavior as @MateuszKubuszok said. Is it a known limitation or may be a bug that should be reported to Scala team?

Comment: @mixel: considering how often I have similar issues with e.g. macwire I would say that this is Scala 2 limitation, and one of the things they intend to fix in Dotty.

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok It seems that it's Scala 2.11.* issue/limitation because in 2.12.0 second case also compiles and runs as expected.