# Import implicits from object that passed as method parameter vs class constructor parameter

Tags: scala, implicit

I have the following code:

```
case class Custom(value: Int)
case class Custom2(value: Float)

case class MappedEncoding[I, O](f: I => O)

trait Decoders {
  type BaseDecoder[T] = () => T
  type Decoder[T] <: BaseDecoder[T]
}

trait ConcreteDecoders extends Decoders {
  type Decoder[T] = ConcreteDecoder[T]

  case class ConcreteDecoder[T](decoder: () => T) extends BaseDecoder[T] {
    def apply(): T = decoder()
  }

  implicit def optionDecoder[T](implicit d: Decoder[T]): Decoder[Option[T]] =
    ConcreteDecoder[Option[T]](() => Some(d()))

  implicit def mappedDecoder[I, O](implicit mapped: MappedEncoding[I, O], decoder: Decoder[I]): Decoder[O] =
    ConcreteDecoder[O](() => mapped.f(decoder()))

  implicit def intDecoder: Decoder[Int] = ConcreteDecoder[Int](() => 1)
  implicit def floatDecoder: Decoder[Float] = ConcreteDecoder(() => 1)

}

class ConcreteContext extends ConcreteDecoders {
}

case class TestObject() {

  implicit val customDecoder = MappedEncoding[Int, Custom](Custom)
  implicit val custom2Encoder = MappedEncoding[Custom2, Float](_.value) // 1
  implicit val custom2Decoder = MappedEncoding[Float, Custom2](Custom2)

  def a(c: ConcreteContext): Unit = {
    import c._
    implicitly[Decoder[Option[Custom]]] // 2
//  implicitly[Decoder[Float]]          // 3
    implicitly[Decoder[Option[Float]]]
    ()
  }
}


object Main extends App {
  implicit val c = new ConcreteContext()

  TestObject().a(c)
  // TestObject(a).()
}
```

And it does not compile in Scala 2.11.8 and 2.12.0 with error:

```
diverging implicit expansion for type c.Decoder[Option[Float]]
[error] starting with method intDecoder in trait ConcreteDecoders
[error]     implicitly[Decoder[Option[Float]]]
```

Using `-Xlog-implicits` option gives long output but the most interesting part is:

```
floatDecoder is not a valid implicit value for c.Decoder[Float] because:
[info] diverging implicit expansion for type c.Decoder[T]
[info] starting with method intDecoder in trait ConcreteDecoders
[info]     implicitly[Decoder[Option[Float]]]
```

Moving `c: CustomContext` from method parameter to case class constructor parameter makes it compile. I thought that may be it changes implicits search scope.

Also one of the following actions make it compile:

- commenting line marked with comment `1` (== line 1)
- commenting line 2
- uncommenting line 3

It looks like resolving `implicitly[Decoder[Option[Custom]]]` leaves Scala compiler in state that affects resolving `implicitly[Decoder[Option[Float]]]`.

Why is this happening and how can I make it compile without moving `c: ConcreteContext` from method parameter?

**P.S.** This is simplified code that reproduces the issue. The real code is much more complex and I need to support the case when `ConcreteContext` is passed as a method parameter.

Comment: Something's definitely fishy here.  This seems to be somewhat related to [SI-9625](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9625). That issue also disappears when you turn the method param into a constructor param. On a sidenote, it might also not be the best idea to have your `Decoder` be a subtype of a `Function0`.

Comment: @Jasper-M I made `Decoder` a subtype of `Function0` because of http://stackoverflow.com/q/40391732/746347.

Comment: The obvious workaround `val c0: c.type = c; import c0._` inside `def a(c: ConcreteContext): Unit` is enough for your needs?

Comment: Thank you! That's very interesting that even `val c0 = c; import c0._` is enough. But I should point that I can not change `def a()` implementation. It's code that users of my library write. So we should think of something we could do with `ConcreteContext`, `Decoders` implementation. And of course first of all I want to find explanation of these stranger things.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a full answer.

I haven't any satisfactory explanation why mention of another implicit could drive resolution out of the loop, created by `mappedEncoder` with `custom2Encoder` + `custom2Decoder` pair. I can only guess that existence of `implicitly[Decoder[Float]]` is upping `floatDecoder` priority over noted `custom2...` loop.

But there is nice solution, which may be not the best but viable option, called 
[`shapeless.Lazy`](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/lazy.scala). It sometimes can be used instead of `LowPriority` decomposition to handle more dreadful situation like this.

You can just rewrite your `mappedDecoder` as

```
import shapeless.Lazy

implicit def mappedDecoder[I, O]
  (implicit mapped: MappedEncoding[I, O], 
            decoder: Lazy[Decoder[I]]): Decoder[O] =
    ConcreteDecoder[O](() => mapped.f(decoder.value()))
```

to make original code work